# Is this math valid?

Tags: statistics

Missing Microbes: How the Overuse of Antibiotics Is Fueling Our Modern Plagues by Martin J. Blaser.

Foods on our supermarket shelves are allowed maximum residue limits for antibiotics, establishing upper boundaries for what is permitted. For example, milk can legally have up to 100 micrograms of tetracycline per kilogram. **This means that a child who drinks two cups of milk a day will ingest about 50 micrograms of tetracycline every day.** That is not a lot, but consider the fact that many children drink milk every day, year after year. And that level is just for tetracycline. All other antibiotics have their own allowable limits. A 1990 report indicated that 30-80 percent of milk samples had detectable antibiotics, especially sulfa drugs and tetracycline (84-85).

I think the math doesn't support the claim in bold. The claim could only be true if the drug was in an uniform distribution throughout the entire kilogram of milk and that each cup had exactly 25 micrograms of the drug.   What would be a better analysis.

Comment: I think the assumption is that the milk contains 100 micrograms per **kilogram**. Since two cups is about half of a kilogram, it would then contain about 50 micrograms.

Comment: Maybe the question is: if milk can legally have *up to* 100 μg/kg of tetracycline, then it is unreasonable to suppose that all milk has exactly this amount.  Instead, we would expect the concentration of tetracycline to be distributed randomly with a very small probability of exceeding the legal limit, and a mean concentration substantially below the limit.  If this is the case then the claim that “a child who drinks two cups of milk a day will ingest about 50 micrograms of tetracycline every day” is incorrect; the expected amount of tetracycline in the two cups of milk will be less than that.

Comment: @MJD On the other hand, it is not unreasonable to assume the worst-case scenario in questions about regulation, esp. public health.

Comment: Sure, but that is a question of public health policy, not a question of mathematics. Perhaps there is some empirical fact about distributions in cases like this, say along the same sort of lines as the Gompertz mortality law, or Zipf's law for distribution of words in a text, which would allow one to conclude that the two cups of milk are *likely* to have around $\frac\pi4$ of the legal maximum amount of antibiotics. If there is such a useful heuristic, a mathematician might know it.

Comment: @MJD, How did you obtain $\pi/4$?

Comment: I made it up, as an example of the *kind* of thing that *might* be true. You should not take it seriously.

Comment: A thing that is sad about science journalism, and that is even sadder about science itself, is that the scientists are bad at math, so they lean on statistics. But being bad at math and leaning on statistics makes your statistics worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the statement exactly as written, the claim is not plausible.  The fact that a kilogram of milk *can* *legally* contain $100$ micrograms of tetracycline does not imply that a typical kilogram of milk purchased at a store *will* contain $100$ micrograms of tetracycline.

Without further knowledge of the state of regulation of the milk industry, we have two likely cases: either enforcement is good, which means the producers will be forced to keep the mean concentrations much lower than $100$ micrograms per kilogram (because process control to keep it near that value is pointless and impractical), or enforcement is lax, in which case there is no telling how much tetracycline is in a given kilogram of milk--it could be much more than $100$ micrograms per kilogram.

What would be correct to say is, *if* a kilogram container of milk contained the maximum legal level of tetracycline, then we *would* expect a child drinking two $250$-milliliter glasses of milk from that container to consume $50$ micrograms of tetracycline.  (Even if the concentration of tetracycline were non-uniform within the container, the *expected* dose from an unspecified half kilogram--as a matter of probability--would still be $50$ micrograms.)

One might perhaps argue that in the phrase "this means", the word "this" refers to the case where the milk contains the maximum allowable amount of tetracycline, so that the sentence in bold is merely an "if" statement much like my previous paragraph; but the author then goes on to relate this to all the milk drunk by many children year after year, implying that we should apply the statement about $50$ micrograms to all these children, and that is not supportable.  The study cited at the end actually undercuts the point, because it indicates that in $20$ to $70$ percent of the samples, investigators were unable to detect *any* trace of *any* antibiotics.

And it's unfortunate that the math is so sloppy, because pervasive antibiotics are a public health risk (in at least some instances), and accurate numbers would be useful guidance in trying to decide what part of that problem to address most vigorously.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and I wanted to make sure that I understand the English correctly of the math statement.

Comment: Yes, I believe you do. It is possible that the _writing_ of the statement is poor, but based on your other comments, your _reading_ of the statement was a correct one.